# Purpose of service definition for ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, feature-layer, service-definition

Whenever I upload e.g. a feature layer to AGOL, I see in AGOL the feature layer AND a **service definition**. I am curious what this **service definition** is.

You can ask the same thing of the **scene layer package** whenever you upload a 3D model to AGOL.

When I delete this **service definition**, does it have consequences like maybe I cannot update my feature layers anymore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you will delete service definiton you will not be able to overwrite//update your service.

Source:
https://community.esri.com/thread/90669

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but with the dominance of Pro I wanted to add the following:

If you published the service from ArcGIS **Pro** and are using Pro to overwrite, then you **don't need** the SD file.

If using **ArcMap**, you still **need** the SD file.

I am not sure how it is handled if you published from ArcMap but are overwriting with Pro. My guess is that you will need the SD file.